# Raleigh men's venture 7speed comfort bike xl steel frame bottom bracket bracket removel tool's needed

Tags: bottom-bracket, raleigh

I have a Raleigh venture 7speed XL 22 inches steel frame men's comfort bike.

In doing an internet search it comes up with venture 2,3,4 with aluminum frame mine has a steel frame.  I can't find what year it was built.  I tried the serial number nothing mine starts with the letter (U)

Just need brand of bottom bracket and tools needed to remove thanks .

---

Thanks, I now know what tools are needed. This my first European bike I have owned and yes my BB is a squared tapered cup and cone.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Exchange. We need a picture to proceed as there are too many different bottom bracket styles out there. So please edit your question, and provide some clear pictures of the bottom bracket, both sides; and any identifying markings.

Comment: Raleigh has used "venture" for many years and has even applied it to some of their recent eBikes. There are many different BB standards. It's a fairly safe bet your BB is a square taper, so you'll need a crank-arm puller. Additionally you'll need one or more wrenches/spanner depending on the interface. Without seeing it I'd bet it has internal splines, that being said it could have external notches. Take a look at the following for more info: https://www.parktool.com/en-us/blog/repair-help/bottom-bracket-tool-selection-threaded-and-thread-together